# How to edit inline buttons?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have two menu buttons. Depends on which of it's used bot have to return different inline buttons. So the first buttons works correct, but how to edit this message if I use the second one

```
 def first(m):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['1menubutton', '2menubutton']])   
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Choose button!',
        reply_markup=keyboard)

def name(m):
    if m.text == '1menubutton':
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['1inlinebutton']])
    elif m.text =='2menubutton':
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['2inlinebutton']])
```

I tried like this, but it does not work:

```
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(m.chat.id, message_id=m.message_id, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use editMessageReplyMarkup like [this example payload](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?editMessageReplyMarkup-6fd81d4c).

Comment: As I said , I tried with editmessagereplymarkup. It doesn't work